# Disable Suggestions when Adding New Items for a List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-form

When you add a new item in a list, a dialog box is displayed together with its columns. When I try to enter a value for a certain column, a dropdown list is shown and all other inputted values for that column are being displayed in the dropdown list.

How can I disable this Suggestion feature for my columns when adding a new Item in the List?

Can it be done via SharePoint Designer or in the actual SharePoint list page?

Answer (score 0):

Form suggestions are controlled by Auto Complete/Auto Fill browser settings. To turn-off this settings for various browsers, follow steps given below:

**Google Chrome:**

- Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
- Select Settings.
- Click Show advanced settings and find the "Passwords and forms" section.
- Deselect the "Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click" checkbox.

**Internet Explorer**

- Open Internet Explorer.
- Click Tools Internet explorer tools icon in the upper right-hand corner.
- Select Internet Options from the dropdown menu.
- Under the Content tab, in the Autocomplete section, click the Settings button.
- Within this window, you can select the fields in which you'd like to store Autocomplete data by using the checkboxes.
- This action turns Autocomplete On or Off based on what boxes are checked.
  Once you have made your selections, click OK.

**Mozilla Firefox**

- Open Firefox.
- Click Menu Firefox Menu Icon in the upper right-hand corner of the screen.
  Select Options from the dropdown menu.
- Under the Privacy tab, in the History section, click the down arrow in the box next to Firefox will: and select Use custom settings for my history.
  A number of checkboxes should appear allowing you to customize what Firefox remembers from your browsing. The box labeled Remember search and form history toggles Autocomplete On or Off.
- Once you have made you browsing privacy selections, click OK.